VPN status icons in network-manager-applet missing

In the nm-applet tray menu missing icons which show status of VPN: is it connected or not. I'm pretty sure when I was using some awesomeWM theme they were there.
Tray icon can be changed through GTK icon-theme but I didn't find how to add/change icons of VPN connection status.
I was trying to managed it through icon-theme of GTK but it seems for me that it doesn't work
Question:
How to fix this issue and add icons for VPN connection status (like appeared lock when VPN is connected)
Note:
System: Manjaro
WM: Sway
Sway set up with gtk theming: icons, applications themes and etc.
